# list of strings sorting and searching throwing run time errors

Tags: vb.net, list, sorting, search

I working with List(Of) in VB.NET.  I would like to "sort" a list by a key/unique field (FEIN), but get an error.  I created the list with three columns (FEIN, Status, Term_Date).  This list loads fine.  Additionally, I would like to "search" this list in a quick and efficient way (BinarySearch?).  I attempted using FindIndex, but it is very slow.  I realize my sort/search syntax assumes a single column list, but I'm trying to get this to work with a multi-column list.  I attached my code with comments and errors.  I'm working in Visual Studio 2019, VB.NET

'define columns in list

```
Public Class AddInfo
    'custom class additional info
    Public Property FEIN As String
    Public Property Status As String
    Public Property Term_Date As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal FEIN As String,
                    ByVal Status As String,
                    ByVal Term_Date As String)

        Me.FEIN = FEIN
        Me.Status = Status
        Me.Term_Date = Term_Date
    End Sub
End Class
```

'populate list (3 columns) from source datatable (dtAddInfo), this list populates nicely

```
Dim lstAddInfo = New List(Of AddInfo)
For Each r As DataRow In dtAddInfo.Rows
    lstAddInfo.Add(New AddInfo(r("FEIN"), r("Status"), r("Term_Date")))
Next
```

'sort newly populated list by FEIN

```
lstAddInfo.Sort()  'this throws "Failed to compare two elements in the array."
```

'find index/row in list using FEIN

```
Dim index = lstAddInfo.BinarySearch("123"))  'this throws "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type"
```

'NOTE: I tried using the following instead of BinarySearch.  It works, but is painfully slow (list contains 220K rows)

> ```
> Dim index = lstAddInfo.FindIndex(Function(x) x.FEIN = "123")) 'search for FEIN in list
> ```

Comment: For the first error: `lstAddInfo.Sort()  'this throws "Failed to compare two elements in the
> array.`  You need to make your `AddInfo` class Implement [IComparable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1?view=net-5.0).  How should instances of `AddInfo` be sorted taking into account the three columns of data?

Comment: You should read [this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/06/sorting-arrays-and-collections-part-1.html) to understand how sorting works in .NET. There are three parts so be sure to read all three.

Comment: Thank you Idle_Mind.  The IComparable link you provided was very useful.  I got my list sorted correctly (ascending by FEIN, first column).  But...I'm still left with the problem of searching the sorted list in an efficient/quick manner.  I tried various binary search methods, but nothing seems to work.  I'm not positive, but it seems the multi-column list is the issue.

Comment: "list contains 220K rows" Can you reduce the number of records being pulled?  Can you query the DataTable instead?  Can you query the source of the DataTable instead?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I cannot reduce the number of rows from the source database table.  But...I was able to track down another alternative.  I used a LINQ query to join the two datatables (Excel and AddInfo) to create a new, pared-down target datatable based on FEIN.  This seems to speed things up significantly.  I attached the code for building a joined datatable.  Thanks again.

```
    'use LINQ query to join Excel and Add Info datatables on FEIN
    Dim joinedResults =
            From Excl In dt_Excel.AsEnumerable()
            Join AddInfo In dt_Add_Info.AsEnumerable()
            On Excl.Field(Of String)("FEIN") Equals AddInfo.Field(Of String)("FEIN")
            Select
            FEIN = Excl.Field(Of String)("FEIN"),
            Status = AddInfo.Field(Of String)("Status"),
            Term_Date = AddInfo.Field(Of String)("Term_Date")

    'define target datatable
    dt_Add_Info = New DataTable
    dt_Add_Info.Columns.Add("FEIN", GetType(String))
    dt_Add_Info.Columns.Add("Status", GetType(String))
    dt_Add_Info.Columns.Add("Term_Date", GetType(String))

    'populate target datatable
    For Each row In joinedResults
        Dim dr As DataRow = dt_Add_Info.NewRow()
        dr("FEIN") = row.FEIN
        dr("Status") = row.Status
        dr("Term_Date") = row.Term_Date
        dt_Add_Info.Rows.Add(dr)
    Next
```